# Timeout reading a post request containing heavy dictionnary

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, timeout

I am receiving a POST request containing a 3 mB Json dictionary. When i receive de POST, my view tries to read the args in the request but that causes a timeout on the Heroku server. When i try it locally, it works fine though.
Here is the code:

```
def send_request():
    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    data = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post(url=url_recette, data=data)
    return response
    
@csrf_exempt
def view(request):
    print('the server gets here')
    _args = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print('the server never gets here so the timeout occurs when i load the args')
```

error on Heroku =>

```
Jan 13 09:00:03 gestion app[web] INFO [2023-01-13 09:00:03 +0100] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
Jan 13 09:00:03 gestion heroku[router] error at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/resiliation/api_get_requete_from_ak" host=gestion-recette.herokuapp.com request_id=xx fwd="xxxx.231" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30826ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
Jan 13 09:00:04 gestion app[web] INFO [2023-01-13 09:00:04 +0100] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem? thx in advance.

Comment: your connection is timing out on Heroku after 30s. how long does it take to process locally?

Comment: that's instantaneous on my local server

Comment: you are not returning a response I think, Heroku error H13 is returned, see the docs here → https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response

Comment: although looking at the timing, it seems you are passing the 30 second timeout. This one cannot be changed on Heroku. See the relevant docs here → https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: I am returning a Jsonresponse just i did not put the rest of the function. It doesnt get further than this though. Th problem occurs when i try to load de request body